# Java: Super class won't override function

Tags: java, superclass, overriding

I have been working on a game for a while and I would like to have a different class for each type of Creature that there is. Right now, all of the different creatures' AI is run in a long switch and I would like a superclass to ovveride that function with that AI for that creature. I have this set up but it won't override.

Am I forgetting something?

Bunny.java:

```
package creature;

import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;

import creature.Creature;
import creature.CreatureType;
import data.Tile;

public class Bunny extends Creature{

    public Bunny(CreatureType type, float x, float y, float speed1) {
        super(type, x, y, speed1);

    }

    public void AI(int type) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

Creature.java:

```
public Creature(CreatureType type, float x, float y, float speed1) {
    this.texture = drawImg(type.textureName);
    this.textureHamster = drawImg("creatures/HamsterFace");
    this.healthBackground = drawImg("health_background");
    this.healthForeground = drawImg("health_foreground");
    this.healthBorder = drawImg("health_border");
    this.startTile = startTile;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.intX = (int) x;
    this.intY = (int) y;
    this.width = texture.getImageWidth();
    this.height = texture.getImageHeight();
    this.speed1 = speed1;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.intspeed = speed;
    this.grid = grid;
    this.health = type.health;
    this.inithealth = type.health;
    this.hiddenHealth = health;
    this.startHealth = health;
    this.dir = false;
    this.dchosen = false;
    this.setx = 0;
    this.hurt = 0;
    this.panick = 0;
    this.deathWish = 0;
    this.pdir = -1;
    this.myX = x;
    this.myY = HEIGHT / 2;
    this.right = false;
    this.left = false;
    this.fade = 0;
    this.fir = true;
    this.aiType = type.aiType;
    this.yOffset = 0;
}

.....

public void AI(int type) {
    if(panic > 0)
        panic--;
    hurt();
    speed = speed1;
    switch(type) {

    case 1:
        if(panic > 0) {
            if(pickRandom(150, 300) < 10) {
                direction = !direction;
            }

            if(direction) {
                if(!right) {
                    x += speed;
                } else {
                    if(falling < 2)
                    gravity = 8;
                }
            } else {
                if(!left) {
                    x -= speed;
                } else {
                    if(falling < 2)
                    gravity = 8;
                }
            }

        } else {
            if(getRange(WIDTH / 2, myX) > 200) {
                directionCoolDown++;
                if(directionCoolDown > pickRandom(150, 3000)) {
                    direction = !direction;
                    directionCoolDown = 0;
                }



                if(direction) {
                    if(!right) {
                        x += speed / 3.2;
                    } else {
                        if(falling < 2)
                        gravity = 8;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(!left) {
                        x -= speed / 3.2;
                    } else {
                        if(falling < 2)
                        gravity = 8;
                    }
                }


            } else {
                if(myX < WIDTH / 2) {
                    direction = true;
                } else {
                    direction = false;
                }




            }
        }
        break;

    case 2:

        yOffset = -25;
        if(!angry) {
            pdir = 0;
            if(getRange(Player.getX(), myX) < 300) {
                hamsterFace = true;
            } else {
                hamsterFace = false;
            }

            if(!hamsterFace) {
                directionCoolDown++;
                if(directionCoolDown > pickRandom(150, 3000)) {
                    direction = !direction;
                    directionCoolDown = 0;
                }

                if(direction) {
                    if(!right) {
                        x += speed / 3.2;
                    } else {
                        if(falling < 2)
                        gravity = 8;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(!left) {
                        x -= speed / 3.2;
                    } else {
                        if(falling < 2)
                        gravity = 8;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            pdir++;
            hamsterFace = false;
            if(myX < Player.getX()) {
                direction = true;
            } else {
                direction = false;
            }

            if(direction) {
                if(!right) {
                    x += speed / 1;
                } else {
                    if(falling < 2)
                    gravity = 8;
                }
            } else {
                if(!left) {
                    x -= speed / 1;
                } else {
                    if(falling < 2)
                    gravity = 8;
                }
            }

            if(getRange(myX, Player.getX()) < 5 && getRange(myY, Player.getY()) < 5) {
                hurtPlayer(-2);
                direction = !direction;
                if(direction) {
                    if(!right) {
                        x += speed * 10;
                    } else {
                        if(falling < 2)
                        gravity = 8;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(!left) {
                        x -= speed * 10;
                    } else {
                        if(falling < 2)
                        gravity = 8;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(panic > 1) { 
            angry = true;
        } else { 
            if(pdir > pickRandom(1000,2000)) {
                angry = false;
            }
        }

        break;

    }
}

.....
```

(Both classes are in the same package)

EDIT: I fixed the typo....

Comment: I don't see a method with signature `void AI()` in your `Creature` class, so there is nothing to override here.

Comment: Also, I don't see a method with signature `void AI(int)` in your `Bunny` class, so it cannot override anything.

Comment: Add `@Override` to the method you are overwriting. Your IDE will tell you whats wrong

Comment: It's not good design to create a separate class for all entities. If only their attributes change (appearance, health, position) they can share a class. However if their behaviour changes (flying enemy vs. walking enemy) separate classes can make sense.

Comment: Can you post the way you are calling the method?

Comment: I am calling it through a update method which is then called by my game class and so on.

Answer (score 2):

you have in the Bunny class:

```
public void AI() {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

in the Creature class:

```
public void AI(int type) {
    if(panic > 0)
    ....
```

so

`void AI(int type)` and  `void AI()`  are **NOT** the same method (check the signature and how they take different parameters!)

therefore the Bunny class is not overriding anything from the parent class

--
edit:

now that your classes have a method `void AI(int type)` then we can say that 
Bunny override the Creature AI method and everytime you call `bunny.AI(f)` your bunny method will be called!

Comment: This still doesn't work... after putting the override annotation, I get no errors. I feel like it isn't being called... do I need to call it?

Comment: But you changed the methods signature to public void AI(int type)? If override gives errors, then the parent method is not found.